# Do i need to accept ExtensionDataObject in API response? C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

Need to call 3rd party API RESTful endpoint and in response example i see that there is, for example:

```
Id: int,
Name: string,
ExtensionData: System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
```

Creating model class to accept that response in C#:

```
public class Response {
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject;
}
```

Visual studio suggests to add reference to System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.

Do i really need it? Or maybe i could not accept ExtensionDataObject? Or is it ok to create class like this?

Comment: Assuming you are using `DataContractJsonSerializer` and [tag:wcf] to deserialize, **if you do not need to round-trip your data** and only need `Id` and `Name`, you should be able to manually remove `IExtensibleDataObject` and omit `ExtensionDataObject` from your model.  The unknown properties will get discarded.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using [tag:wcf] and that your requirement is to ignore unknown properties?

Answer (score 0):

When accepting `ExtensionData`you must inherit the class from `IExtensibleDataObject`

```
public class Person : IExtensibleDataObject
{
   private ExtensionDataObject extensionDataObject_value;
   public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
   {
       get
       {
            return extensionDataObject_value;
        }
        set
        {
            extensionDataObject_value = value;
        }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name;
}
```

For more detailed please check this [ExtensionDataObject Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.extensiondataobject?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Answer is not what i asked. I know how to accept it. Question was should I?
After trying it, it is not necessary.